# Drawing polygons for each row in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an Excel file, as shown below. Each row contains several points (x,y). Depending on the number of points in each row, I want to draw polygons for each row in MATLAB. How do this work?

For one row, I did the following:

```
x=[49.2 49.2 50.081 50 49.2 ]; 
y=[36.8 37 36.86 36.594 36.8 ]; 
patch(x,y,'g');
```

but I can't figure out how to read all rows from the file and create patches for each row.

My Excel file looks like this:

```
x         y       x       y,...
49.4    35.583  49.424  35.828  51.02   35.766  50.9    35.52   49.4    35.583      
50.933  36.836  50.931  36.586  52.224  36.163  52.21   36.527  50.933    36.836        
50.23   36.168  51.232  36.164  51.779  35.977  51.72   35.68   51.02   35.766  50.23   36.168
```

The resulting plot should looke like this:

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Did you google for "matlab draw polygon"?

Comment: yes but cant any work

Comment: So please edit your question to show the code you have tried, and explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: for example for one row [k, l]=size(p);     x=[49.2  49.2  50.081  50  49.2  
  ];

 y=[36.8         37          36.86     36.594    36.8
];

patch(x,y,'g');

Comment: Ok, good. And are you unhappy with the way this polygon is shown? Or is the problem in reading all points from the file? Or going through all rows?

Comment: yes im problem with  reading all points from the file and Drawing polygons for each row  i wanted plot like top image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read an Excel file using the [`xlsread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) function. You can also supply a sheet name, and a range, e.g.

```
X = xlsread('myFile.xls', 'Sheet 1', 'B1:D5');
```

this is, however, optional. To read all content of the first sheet of the file, simply use

```
X = xlsread('myFile.xls');
```

Note: this returns only the *numeric* data, so the header will automatically be removed. You will thus have a matrix `X`, containing all rows. So we can start plotting. We first show the background image, and then do a for loop which goes through all rows of the matrix:

```
% Show background image
figure(1);
imshow(yourBackgroundImage);

% Specify different colors (taken from https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/8558-plot-different-colors-while-using-loops)
% Note: you need as many entries / colors in this cell array as you have rows in your file!
C = {'k','b','r','g','y',[.5 .6 .7],[.8 .2 .6]} 

% Go through all rows
for k=1:size(X,1)
    % Take k-th row and reshape it so x is on first row and y on second row
    y = reshape(X(k,:), 2, []);

    % Draw polygon with no FaceColor (i.e. not filled)
    patch(y(1,:), y(2,:), 'b', 'EdgeColor', C{k}, 'FaceColor', 'None');
end
```